# How to resolve ambiguity between branch name and commit hash in git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-diff

I have a branch named `0726b` and I want to diff my current working copy with that branch.
Apparently there is also a commit that has a hash starting with that very sequence, because I get

```
$ git diff 0726b
warning: refname '0726b' is ambiguous.
```

How do I tell git that it should take the argument as a branch name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
git diff refs/heads/0726b
```

---

`refs/heads/0726b` specifies a branch named **0726b**.
The file `./git/refs/heads/0726b` contains the commit hash that this branch points to.