# Permanently fixing ambiguity between branch name and commit hash

Tags: git

So I have some git repository:

```
git init
echo "Recipes" > README
git add README
```

Then I make a branch called "beef" to store all my steak recipes:

```
git checkout -b beef
```

A while goes by and then someone makes a commit:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='Tue Jan 1 00:00:00 2019 -0400' \
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='Tue Jan 1 00:00:00 2019 -0400' \
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='Chef' \
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='<chef@localhost>' \
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Chef' \
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='<chef@localhost>' \
git commit -m "New recipe:00100011000001010000000010100000"
git checkout -b master
```

Uh oh... the commit hash starts with `beef`! [1] Now, every time I want to switch to my beef branch, I get this annoying message: `warning: refname 'beef' is ambiguous.`

Worse yet, if I clone the repository elsewhere and try to checkout the beef branch for the first time, I instead end up with a detached head on the beef commit! Of course I can workaround this by doing `git checkout --track origin/beef` instead of just `git checkout beef`, but now I need to tell everybody who uses my project about this special workaround.

So, long story short, my question is: I have a branch that is ambiguous with a git commit prefix. How can I tell git once-and-for-all that when I say `beef` I always want to refer to the branch, not the commit? Ideally this should work for anyone who downloads the repository, but even a fix that just works locally would be nice.

Restrictions:

- I can't rename/delete the branch. Other people use this project and they expect the branch to be there and to be named beef.
- I can't amend/remove the offending commit because it has already been pushed to master in a shared repo.
- I don't really want a temporary workaround like the one mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534635/how-to-resolve-ambiguity-between-branch-name-and-commit-hash-in-git) that I'll have to type every time I use the beef branch, I want a way to resolve this problem once and for all.

[1] I spent way too long trying to make that commit have a reproducible hash starting with beef... But yes this is derived from an example I saw in a real repository (branch name changed to protect the innocent).

Comment: Rename the branch and live happily ever after.

Comment: @eftshift0 Sure, but (1) I'm not the only person using this repo, I can't just go willy-nilly renaming branches. (2) The branch name does actually provide a meaningful description of its contents, ideally I would like to keep it instead of changing it to something silly like `beef1` or `not-beef`

Comment: Basically, you can't. This is an argument for putting a non-hexadecimal-character letter into every branch name. (But you *can* use the name `cab` as it's only 3 letters. It's names like `beef`, `cafe`, `babe`, `bead`, `face`, `decade`, and so on that are off limits. You can put hyphens into some, such as the branch whose name commands you to Be Fab(ulous). :-) )

Comment: Use a branch naming style that cannot conflict with a hash. `feature/beef`, `issue/beef`, `fix/beef`, `refactor/beef`.

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be easy fix for now.

I have checked that setting [`core.abbrev`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreabbrev) to an higher number (like 8 or 10 or ... above your branch name length) does not prevent the warning.

It is possible the Git 2.23 command **[`git switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)** will alleviate the issue, since it only switches *branches* (while [`git restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309) would restore a [*tree* content](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f496b064fc1135e0dded7f93d85d72eb0b302c22/Documentation/git-restore.txt#L33-L39), and would therefore still be affected, since a tree can be referenced by a commit or a branch)

I just tested it: that warning remains, but at least, you can only switch to *branches*, so no confusion is possible.

---

Note: as I mention in "[How would Git handle a SHA-1 collision on a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9392525/6309)", you can use [**`bradfitz/gitbrute`**](https://github.com/bradfitz/gitbrute) to force a commit to a particular SHA1 *prefix*.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid this might be the case :(

Comment: @FlightOdyssey Git 2.23 is released. I confirm that `git switch beef` will *always* switch to the *branch* named `beef`.